# Is it safe to use window.screen?

Tags: javascript, dom

MDN explains how to use the `window.screen` object, but also says "[DOM Level 0. Not part of specification.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen)"

W3Schools says that `window.screen.*` properties are [supported in all major browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availwidth.asp).

If I understand this correctly... `window.screen` is completely non-standard, but is nonetheless universally supported. Is that right?

If this is the case, are there any cross-browser differences I need to be aware of, or can I just use it? I'm mostly interested in `screen.availWidth`, by the way.

Comment: if you deviate from standards, your code could break in future browsers.

Comment: The *Screen* interface is specified in the [CSSOM View](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-screen-interface) standard.

Comment: The DOM is really just about abstract documents, so it has no notion of an actual output device. In practice, every browser will of course have to provide an output device of some sort (though you could image `wget` to include a DOM-bound scripting engine that has no output device). That's why `window` isn't in the DOM (though it may well be standardised elsewhere, as Sime's link suggests).

Comment: @Kerrek The *Window* interface is specified in the [HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object) standard. (Btw there are a couple of extensions to the *Window* interface which are specified in other standards...)

Comment: Sime: Personally I like to think of HTML 5 as a large, loose *collection* of many different standards -- it's a huge hodgepodge of all sorts of diverse technologies... but good to know that `window` is included :-)

Comment: @Kerrek Well, they had to put it somewhere `:P` Btw since "HTML5" became such a buzzword lately, the editor of HTML decided to drop that name and go with just "HTML" instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quirksmode compatibility tables to the rescue!

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#screenview

Most, but not *all* values are supported by the major browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You should be fine with it.

The reason that it is not part of a standard is because DOM Level 0 was introduced before standards were around.  DOM Level 0 is also called the Legacy DOM, and it was created at the same time NetScape 2.0 made JavaScript in the browser a reality; in effect, DOM Level 0 was the very first DOM spec.

The Legacy DOM will be around for a long time, if not then it would break backward compatibility with a TON of very popular scripts already in existence.

**EDIT: In other words, your understanding is completely correct.  It is not "standardized" but it is completely universal and will remain so for a long time.**

Comment: But it *is* part of a standard... `>_<`

Comment: window is part of the standard.  The guarantee that window will be holding on to a screen object is not part of the standard.

Comment: @Šime Vidas You're referring to the CSSOM API, which is used by Media Queries (which is done via CSS and has nothing to do with the JavaScript DOM API).  In that respect, yes, screen is standardized.

Comment: No, the CSSOM API is accessible via JavaScript in the browser, so it's effectively a JavaScript API (just like the DOM APIs).

Comment: Huh, I haven't seen that before.  That sounds like it would be really interesting.  Can you show me an example?  The only JavaScript/CSSOM interaction I've seen is in using the DOM extensions to access the computed styles of an element.